# Why is there no agent marker in this sentence?

Tags: syntax

> 風颯々｛かぜさっさつ｝として松の梢｛こずえ｝を吹く.　The wind murmurs in the boughs of the pine trees. ｜ The breeze is soughing in the pine tops. (研究社 新和英大辞典 第５版)

Why isn't 風 here followed by a case marker like は or がif it's treated as the subject of the predicate (颯々として松の梢を吹く)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason is that that is a poetic expression, not a sentence from "regular" prose; therefore, one should not apply the prose grammar to it.

Insert a 「は」 and the sentence will sound much less poetic.